# What is the most efficient way to use a final string in a loop that will loop 2 million times?

Tags: java

I have a situation in which I need to call a function with a set of string values. The strings are constants because they wont be modified. But there is a little bit of logic to decide which string to call the function with. I thought about using an enum, but then decided that would be bad because I would have to call .toString() on that enum 50 times in each iteration of the loop which will be 2 million. What would be the most efficient way solve that issue?

My solution is

```
public class Attributes {
    private Attributes() {}
    public static final MY_STRING = "MyString";
}
```

And then in the loop do:

```
public String myFunction() {

   for(int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++) {
       callThis(Attributes.MY_STRING)
   }

}


public String callThis(String myString) {
   //.... dadaddad
}
```

I am worried about memory, so I want to have these constant strings be used to call the function in the most efficient way possible. Is this the most efficient way? Or what is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: I agree! actually though I have to because the senior expert engineer told me to do this and Im new so I have to. PS. This is part of process that will create about 200 million objects in memory which is unavoidable, but to solve this seems like it would reduce the burden. PS the thing I am doing works on my MBP with 16 GB ram but will crash the server apparently.

Comment: *actually though I have to because the senior expert engineer told me to do this* Told you to do **what**? And if you have question(s), why aren't you speaking with this "expert"?

Comment: Calling toString on an enum is pretty much guaranteed to return the same reference every time

Comment: Sorry I actually wrote it wrong, looping 2 millions times calling the method with the string will happen 50 times in the loop. So its actually 100,000,000 times. I am speaking to the expert but i feel like the way that I have done it is actually fine and his method was quite a bit more complex, and I did not see how it could actually be so much better than what I have there. And I was wondering if there was a best practice, because it doesnt seem like a particularly unusual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's literally impossible to answer 'what's the most efficient way' for Java without reference to JVM, OS, HW, configuration, version and many other factors. Java is a language which can be implemented in different ways with different performance characteristics.

More generally there are very few circumstances in which you need to worry about the efficiency of small snippets of code such as this. The optimiser in most Java implementation is very sophisticated: if you code for clarity and correctness you can generally trust it to do it's job.

You mention looping 2 million times. That's a trivial load for any modern machine. If you write you code in the clearest way you can and find you have a performance issue then you can profile your code and optimise methods that matter. It's notoriously difficult to correctly decide ahead of time what needs to be optimised.

So to summarise, until you know you have a problem ignore performance and code for cleanness and clarity.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in the above comment its actually 50 calls to that function in each iteration of  a loop 2000000 times. So more like 100000000 calls. But anyways I just wanted to make sure that there wasnt like some best practice that I didnt know about... Ive never worked with such large data in a function before, so yeah havent really thought about that kind of optimization until now.